# Where can I find the file in my wordpress site to edit this javascript reference?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am experiencing an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in my wordpress site that I looked into on this thread: [HERE]

I want to change:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.effectivefaculty.org/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/single-product.min.js'></script>
```

To

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//www.effectivefaculty.org/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/single-product.js'></script>
```

(found when I viewed source) essentially sans the min to see if this will solve the problem.

Where in my wordpress files can I find the file that will allow me to change this reference?

Comment: The issue is not with the .min. You _want_ to use the minified version of the file. The problem lies in the leading double slash. With that scheme, the browser is looking for the js file locally, where it won't be stored. You need to add a `http:` before those slashes. If you want to find the file where that include is, do a search through all of the wordpress files for that line.

Comment: Yes, I need to know how I can search for this line. Thank you for the info on the // though I didn't see that!

Comment: Do you have access to the entire wordpress directory? What text editor are you using?

Comment: With sublime text you can do a full project search using shift+super+f and search for that string. Should find it pretty easily, assuming it's not created programatically.

Answer (score 0):

the file you are looking for is here: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/`

I think that the problem might be related with this line:

```
$( '.woocommerce-ordering' ).on( 'change', 'select.orderby', function() {
        $( this ).closest( 'form' ).submit();
    });
```

To change this you should search in the files of the plugin for the name of the minimized file, and comment the line where the wp_enqueue_script or the wp_register_script is.

Anyway, I don't think this is the right way to solve the problem, as it might interfere with the plugin's functionality

Comment: Hmm, I can't find that line in the single-product file.

Comment: That line is in the JS script.